# drop down list box population in sharepoine designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint, drop-down-menu, designer

Is it possible to populate the values in a drop down list box with the unique values from a field in a custom list from the site ? if yes, how to do the same?

Once i insert the DropDownlist, right click gives a Choose data source field, but not finding a way to connect to the list defined in the site :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to create a data source first on the page  [Youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qe7I4qOfVk)

Comment: youtube is not accesble over here :(

Comment: i can't find any other link what you have to do is in SPD go to data-view and click on manage data source. on left a new pane will get opened. find your custom list in that menu and click on your list name a new menu will appear and then click on insert data source control